# howto solve git-samba-shared-repository-problem

Tags: git, ubuntu, samba

We have problems with pushing to a shared repository. The shared repository is hosted on a windows server. The OS with problems is Ubuntu 11.04. Pushing to the shared repository works fine for OS X and Windows.

This is the error we get (after using "git push origin master"):
error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename ./objects/fb:

The Ubuntu user can create and access files without problems in the windows server.

Any hints?

Comment: How are you accessing the windows server from ubuntu?  ssh?  SMB?  smart-http? What happens if you try using a different access method (if possible)

Comment: @Seth we mounted the windows folder via SMB and cloned into it '~/.gvfs/server/Repository' Are there better ways to do that?

Comment: What arguments did you use to create the shared repository on the windows server?  More specifically what is the value of `git config core.sharedRepository` when run against the shared repository, and what are the permissions on ..../sharedrepo/.git/objects and objects/fb (or whatever the enclosing directory was)

Comment: @Seth We created the shared repository with `git --bare init --shared`   The value of `git config core.sharedRepository` wasn't set and and setting it to true didn't solve the problem as reported by others...

Answer (score 0):

If core.sharedRepository was not set, then that was almost certainly the problem.  Running the command you quoted worked properly for me.  However, setting the value to true does not retroactively fix any previously incorrect actions.  You will need to recursively reset the permissions and group ownership of the files and directories in the shared git repository.

I'm not specifically sure how to do this on your windows server, not the least because you didn't identify what version of windows.  However, at a normal shell prompt (and the msysgit might well provide this command on the windows box) you can cd to the shared git repository directory and run:

```
chmod -R ug+rwX .
chgrp -R groupname .
```

You obviously need to pick the valid group name yourself.  Another option is to change the core.sharedRepository value to "all", modify the permissions with `chmod -R a+rwX .` and then the group setting is irrelevant.